# Output not working and no console error

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `Output()` decorator, but I think it is not working because maybe I am missing something? There are no console errors, so it is a problem for me as this is the first time I am working with `Output()`. The following is my code.

game-control.component.html

```
import { Component, 
  OnInit, 
  Input, 
  Output, 
  EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css']
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {

  age = 0;
  @Output() startClicked = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onStartClick(){
    this.startClicked.emit("this has clicked "+this.age++);
  }

  constructor() {
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

game-control.component.html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onStartClick()">Start</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>{{value}}</h1>

      <app-game-control (onStartClick)="parentFromChild($event)">
      </app-game-control>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  value = 'Ammar';

parentFromChild(message){
  this.value = message;
}

  constructor(){

  }
}
```

The page is empty and no error in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is named `startClicked`, so you need to use that from the parent.

```
  <app-game-control (startClicked)="parentFromChild($event)">
  </app-game-control>
```

Comment: Thanks, output() is hard, is nested component talking to eachother the most wanted and useful in anguar?

Comment: Yes. Use `Output()` to emit events and listen to them from the parent component. It's not that difficult, just practice it a few times. You'll be doing a lot of that in your apps.